# Installing Skype on Debian stretch/sid 64 bit without breaking the system

Tags: installation, debian, 64-bit, skype, apt

I'm not able to install skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb on Debian stretch/sid amd64.

I followed [the guide in the Skype website](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12120/getting-started-with-skype-for-linux#2) for Debian 7+ at 64 bit, that states to:

- `dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update`
- download and install Skype for *Debian 7.0 (multiarch)*

But installing it through gdebi gives me:

> Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl1.0.0.

There is a lot of literature on how to fix the issue, but often
it consists in forcing installation with `apt-get install -f` and/or
adding repositories in the apt sources list.

The problem with that is that I already followed those kind of instructions under previous versions of Debian and at least two times **I broke my system**.

That means that e.g. I couldn't anymore install some packages such as vlc because of dependencies' conflicts or even couldn't install any packages at all or update my system through apt.

My question is: is there a way to install Skype on this platform without having to create a Frankenstein Debian?

Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit `sources.list` and add the following lines:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ sid main 
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

Save and update

Try the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install libc6:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

Install the 32-bit variant of libxcursor1.

```
apt-get install libxcursor1:i386
```

You can install skype trough `gdbi`

First, you will have to enable Multi-Arch; to do so type in the following commands in ROOT Terminal:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

Then, download the i386 package as above and install:

```
apt-get install gdebi
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
gdebi skype-install.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I fear that adding sid's repositories could make my system inconsistent.

Comment: Try `gdbi` without adding sid's repo